# How to pin "Programs and Features" and "Device Manager" to Start Menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

In Windows 7 I could search for a settings page like "Programs and Features" or "Device Manager" in the start menu and then right-click it to pin it to the start menu. In Windows 10 I can only pin the settings app to the start menu but not the specific pages. Is there another way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to pin pages from the modern Settings app to the start menu, that's quite easy: Just right click on an entry on the left hand side and click "Pin to start":
[image: Modern settings app]

---

With "Programs and features" it's almost as easy as with the modern settings app: Search for it in the desktop control panel, right-click it and click "Pin to start":
[image: Programs and features (control panel)]

---

With the device manager it's a bit more complicated. First, you have to find the file **. C:\Windows\System32\devmgmt.msc**. Right-click on it and choose "Pin to start". This will create a start menu tile with the ugly name "devmgmt". To change this, right-click on the tile, choose "Open file path" and change the shortcut's name to something nicer (e.g. "Device manager").

---

It's important that (in the control panel) "Pin to start" or "Create shortcut" will only appear, if the desired setting appears in a big font (like "Programme und Features" [german for "Programs and features] and "Geräte-Manager" [german for "Device manager"] on the screenshots do).

Comment: After I created a shortcut to the devices manager, there is no "Pin to start" entry in the context menu of the desktop shortcut.

Comment: @cypressious Yes, you were right. I changed the instructions, now they should work properly.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm accepting this answer, because it answers the original question.

Answer (score 7):

There's an easier way. Simply right-click the Start button:

[image: Power user menu screenshot]

Comment: That's awesome! The right-click menu quickly becomes my favorite new feature.

Comment: I've accepted the other answer, because it answers the original question. Your tip is great, nevertheless.